# Average cost for host Node Project in AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new in Node development, how much average cost I need to pay to Amazon web services(AWS)if I host my Node Project in AWS EC2 with PM2.

Comment: What are the resource requirements for your app? There are details required to give a cost, even an average. If you can get away with a single EC2 instance with 1GB RAM and low utilisation of a single CPU then AWS could be free for a whole year, then a few dollars per month. If you need redundancy, load balancing, DB, persistent storage etc then maybe not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what ec2 you spin up. You need to choose right instance type. Since you mentioned PM2 , I am assuming you are ruling out ECS OR docker deployment.

If running in a single process, Nodejs dosent exploit multi core CPUs (as compare to other language like golang) so best bet for moderate load is m4.large. (2 vcpus) Or start with t2.micro and keep [profiling](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/) your node app.
You can change instance type later as result of your profiling.

You can calculate cost using AWS monthly cost calculator
.

Comment: I plan to run android application API(Node application)

Comment: What would that api do, use cloud hosted database?

Comment: API fulfill the request data of Android application, Android application is a school management application.

Comment: As mentioned by user NHol , get your app sized , start spinning with minimal instance (t2.micro) and then change instance type after done with profiling your app.